# How to finish an Activity that is used in a TabSpec, as the child of TabHost

Tags: android-activity, android-tabhost

I have Main Activity which contains a TabHost.
In the TabHost I have several TabSpec which use an Intent for the content of the tab.

At certain points in my code I need to remove a tab from the TabHost, and finish the Activity that was in that tab's TabSpec.

I am able to remove the tab from the TabHost, but as soon as I call finish on that child Activity, the Main Activity terminates.  I have even tried calling finish some time later, with a timer.  It still kills the main activity.

How can I finish a child activity without killing the main activity?

Comment: Why don't you turn the tab into a Fragment instead of an Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Tab Host was decrapated by google so you shouldnt use it anymore you should replace it using actionbarsherlock its a better option for tabs.